# Comparing column headers of two files to fetch data in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a large CSV file, say INPUT, with about 500+ columns.  I also have a dataframe DF that contains a subset of the column headers of INPUT which changes at every iteration.

I have to fetch the data from only those columns of INPUT that is present in the dataframe DF and write it into another CSV file, say OUTPUT.

In short,

INPUT.csv:

```
ID,Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D,Col_E,Col_F,,,,,,,,,,,,,Col_S,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Col_Z
1,009,abcd,67,xvz,33,50,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,oup,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,90
2,007,efgh,87,wuy,56,67,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,ghj,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,888
```

print(DF):

```
[1] "Col_D" "Col_Z"
[3] "Col_F" "Col_S"
```

OUTPUT.csv

```
ID,Col_D,Col_Z,Col_F,Col_S
1,xvz,90,50,oup
2,wuy,888,67,ghj
```

I'm a beginner when it comes to R. I would prefer for the matching of dataframe with the INPUT file to be automated, because i don't want to do this everyday when the dataframe gets updated.

Comment: read first `input.csv` entirely and then subset

Comment: `input <- read.table(...); input[colnames(input) %in% DF]` assuming DF is a vector with column names

Comment: `fread` is all you need ... `data.table::fread("INPUT.csv", select = c("ID", DF))`

Comment: @joel.wilson: Can u put it up as an answer. i'd like to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the answer :

```
input <- read.table(...)
input[colnames(input) %in% colnames(DF)]
```

Comment: @Ramkrishna does it answer?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly, you need to import the INPUT.csv file inside R and then match the columns of your DF with those columns of your INPUT, is that correct?

you can either use the `match` function or just import the INPUT.csv file inside RStudio via "Import Dataset" button and subset it. Subsetting of imported dataframes is fairly easy. 
If you will import your dataset as INPUT, then you can make the subset of these columns in following way: `INPUT[,c(1,2,4)]`

and that will get you first, second and fourth column of the INPUT dataset.

Comment: i can do this manually, but i'm trying to find a way to automate this process. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, to upload the csv is simple:

```
dataframe_read <- read.csv('/Path/to/csv/')
```

If I understand correctly that one dataframes columns is always a subset, the code is as follows:

```
### Example Dataframes
df1 <- data_frame(one = c(1,3,4), two= c(1,2,3), three = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data_frame(one = c(1,3,4), three= c(1,2,3))

### Make new data frame
df3 <- df1[,colnames(df2)]

### Write new dataframe
write.csv(df3, 'hello.csv')
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, we had a power out.

Comment: What do you mean automate? Like write a function/CRON job?

Comment: exactly, write a function. no worries i got what i wanted